# update python list of lists on multithreaded

Tags: python, arrays, multithreading, list, mutex

I have this simple python code:

```
from threading import Lock, Condition, Thread

n_threads = 5
global_list = [[]]*n_threads

def update_list(t_id, lock):
    global global_list
    for i in range(t_id, t_id+4, 1):
        lock.acquire()
        global_list[t_id].append(i)
        lock.release()
    print('finishing', t_id)

all_threads = []
l = Lock()

for i in range(n_threads):
    c = Thread(name='name %s' % i, target=update_list, args=(i,l,))
    all_threads.append(c)
    c.start()

for my_thread in all_threads:
    my_thread.join()
```

Basically what I am trying to do is that each thread updates one of the lists and by the end of my code each list inside of the variable global_list will have elments from a single thread, like this:

```
global_list[0] = [0,1,2,3]
global_list[1] = [1,2,3,4]
...
```

Instead what I get is :

```
global_list[0] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7]
global_list[1] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7]
...
```

I am using a mutex to protect the operation, so basically I am clueless about why it wont work for lists in python and if threre is something I can use to achieve this.

Comment: `a = [[]]*n_threads` creats `[[], [], [], [], []]` but all the 5 lists are same, they are. And when you are doing `global_list[t_id].append(i)` since other 4 list are just same it gets the value gets copied. Try `copy`

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in [[]]*5:
    print(id(i))
```

output

```
139972923894208
139972923894208
139972923894208
139972923894208
139972923894208
```

So, as you can see `[[]]*5` doesn't create 5 lists, only one list.All other 4 are just representative of the first one.
So when you do

```py
list[0].append(1)
```

it makes the list as

```
[[1],[1],[1],[1],[1]]
```

try

```
global_list = [[], [], [], [], []]
```

or

```
global_list = [[] for i in range(n_threads)]
```

Comment: works flawlessly, Thank you so very much.